# long-range dependence measure

Tags: time-series, self-study, trend, test-for-trend, long-range-dependence

Hurst exponent is a simple, powerful and widely used measure  of a long-term memory of time series.

What is are the disadvantages of this measure for checking long-range dependence in the series and what else could be used instead of Hurst exponent?

Comment: "Analogue of Hurst exponent" for what purpose in what context?

Comment: Dear @whuber, I have clarified. Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you don't mean to write "analogue:" this word connotes a *different context* and asks for what might *substitute* for the Hurst exponent in that context.  So, if "analogue" really is your intention, then please describe the different context; but if it is not your intention, then please formulate your question using a different word.

Comment: Dear @whuber, I have edited the question and the title.